# Prevent OStorageException with graph API using multithreading

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to implement a multithread app in which I populate a graph,
starting from some initial nodes.

I'm using an utility class, named OrientDBAdapter, create for all insert/update/delete operations on database. In OrientDBAdapter I have implemented a method to insert vertex on graph. All vertex are urls and they can be seed urls (loaded at startup time) or not. In this last case they will be inserted in separated threads (one for thread for initial seeds). Every instance of OrientDBAdapter have an instance of graph as unique attribute and the following constructor:

```
private OrientBaseGraph graph;

public OrientDBAdapter(OrientBaseGraph graph) {
    this.graph = graph;
}
```

The followinf is the method for insert urls in OrientDBAdapter:

```
public void addUrlToGraph(String url, boolean isSeed) {
    if (Common.VERBOSE)
        System.out.println("Adding url seed " + url + " into graph");

    try {
        String clusterName = Common.URLS_CLASS_NAME;
        OrientVertex vertex = graph.addVertex(Common.URLS_CLASS_NAME, clusterName);
        vertex.setProperty("url", url);
        vertex.setProperty("seed", isSeed);
    } catch (ORecordDuplicatedException e) {
        if (Common.VERBOSE)
            System.out.println("Vertex with url " + url + " already exists");
    } catch (OStorageException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    graph.commit();
}
```

In my Main class I have implemented following statements for start some instances of Crawler thread:

```
for (Vertex seedsVertex : seedsVertices) {
    String url = seedsVertex.getProperty(Common.URLS_PROP_URL);
    OrientDBAdapter dbAdapter = new OrientDBAdapter(orientDBHelper.getTxGraph());
    Crawler crawler = new Crawler(dbAdapter, url);
    crawler.start();
}
```

I want to launch a thread for each seed: for every Crawler instance I use a new instance of OrientDBAdaper that have a different instance of a graph.

The method getTxGraph() is implemented in another class utilty, named OrientDBHelper, used for creating factory, obtaining graph and for more operations. In this class I have implemented a method for getting a new instance of graph from factory:

```
public OrientGraphNoTx getNoTxGraph() {
    return factory.getNoTx();
}
```

Crawler is a thread implemented as follow:

```
public class Crawler extends Thread {

    private Thread thread;

    private OrientDBAdapter dbAdapter;
    private String urlString;

    public Crawler(OrientDBAdapter dbAdapter, String urlString) {
        this.dbAdapter = dbAdapter;
        this.urlString = urlString;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        //TEST THREAD INSERT INTO GRAPH:
        dbAdapter.addUrlToGraph("http://www.test.com", false);
    }
```

When I'm trying to insert the http://www.test.com url I always obtain the following exception:

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OStorageException: Storage emailextractor is not opened.
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.checkOpeness(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1613)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.storage.impl.local.OAbstractPaginatedStorage.getClusterIdByName(OAbstractPaginatedStorage.java:1023)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.getClusterIdByName(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1251)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.save(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2469)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.save(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:122)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocument.java:1768)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.save(ODocument.java:1764)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientElement.save(OrientElement.java:334)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientBaseGraph.addVertex(OrientBaseGraph.java:624)
at eu.fabiorinnone.emailextractor.database.OrientDBAdapter.addUrlToGraph(OrientDBAdapter.java:40)
at eu.fabiorinnone.emailextractor.database.OrientDBAdapter.addUrlToGraph(OrientDBAdapter.java:31)
at eu.fabiorinnone.emailextractor.extractor.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:45)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: You say that when you try to insert that URL you get the error, does it mean that if you insert other data it works fine?

Comment: The problem is not url, because I'm able to insert correctly url (or any string data) if the method is called in main thread.

Comment: How do you create your graph instance?

Comment: In OrientDBHelper I have a method initializeFactory() in which I create a factory pool using plocal connection. I think the problem is that in the Main class I load seeds on my graph and when Main execution finish it close the storage. But in this moment there are some opened threads that they found storage closed.